# HOw to send data and file from a form using flask?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

i have created a form using html and flask. where user will fill his name , address and other information , and will also upload his photo and other documents. once the user will fill the information and submits the form he will be redirected to another page with his own filled information and photo on the page.

i am able to get user information filled and redirect him to another page "apply.html" but when i am trying to upload photo. it's  able to upload pic but do not redirect me to "apply.html"

in my routes.py

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/form.html', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    nform = NewRegistration(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))


@app.route('/form.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
  nform = NewRegistration(request.form)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if nform.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('form.html', form=nform)
    else:
      post = request.form['element_15'].strip()  
      name = request.form['element_1_1'].strip()
      last = request.form['element_1_2'].strip()
      Name = str(name)+ ' ' +str(last)
      father = request.form['element_2'].strip()
      mother = request.form['element_3'].strip()
      gender = request.form['element_17'].strip()

      data = {'Name' : Name, 'post' : post, 'father' : father}

      return render_template("apply.html", data=data)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('form.html', form=nform)
```

i know the problem is because of two function "upload_file" and "form"  so suggest me the best way to get information and photo and also be able to redirect user to apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you need to add render_template() in

```
@app.route('/form.html', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    // do something
    render_template("yourpage.html")
```

Every route must return a response.
Also I would recommend use the same route for saving file+form.

```
@app.route('/form.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
  nform = NewRegistration(request.form)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if nform.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('form.html', form=nform)
    else:

        try:
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        except Exception as e:
            print "Form without file "+e
        post = request.form['element_15'].strip()
        name = request.form['element_1_1'].strip()
        last = request.form['element_1_2'].strip()
        Name = str(name)+ ' ' +str(last)
        father = request.form['element_2'].strip()
        mother = request.form['element_3'].strip()
        gender = request.form['element_17'].strip()
        data = {'Name' : Name, 'post' : post, 'father' : father}
        return render_template("apply.html", data=data)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('form.html', form=nform)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i did the same before. i tried all . what u told its showing ""POST /form.html HTTP/1.1" 200  means form is being posted. but it is not saving the image , and also not returning to apply.html. 

it keep returning me to the same page again. .

Comment: ok the same worked, for me today. i guess and thankyou. and can you tell me how it's possible to show form data and uploaded image to a page. like it's a student application website , where student will fill his information along with his photo. so when he submits, he will be redirected to another page with his own information filled and a image on the page, kind of admit card.

Comment: Now use jinja template to parse the data you are passing through
render_template( "apply.html" , data=data ) .
Your apply.html should look something like this :

`{% if data %}
  Name  : {{ data['Name'] }}
  Father : {{ data['father'] }}
{% endif %}`

The more data you pass  on render_template("apply.html" , data=data) , the same can be rendered on the page.